# Sending http(s) requests via http proxy server in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, https, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to send http (GET and POST requests) to various sites to retrieve response header/body information, and need to vary whether I am using a proxy or not. After previously failing to use restler library for this purpose, I have switched to node 'http' and 'https' libraries to perform these tasks. Code as follows:

```
/******/
//Http client libraries
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");

//Request URL
var url = 'http://whatismyip.akamai.com';
//var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page';

//Proxy config
var USE_PROXY = false;
var PROXY_PROTOCOL= 'http';
var PROXY_HOST= '127.0.0.1';
var PROXY_PORT= 6401;

/******/

//Define request options
var protocol = (USE_PROXY ? (PROXY_PROTOCOL == 'https' ? https : http) : (getProtocolFromUrl(url) == 'https' ? https : http));
var host = (USE_PROXY ? PROXY_HOST : getDomainFromUrl(url));
var port = (USE_PROXY ? PROXY_PORT : (getProtocolFromUrl(url) == 'https' ? 443 : 80));
var path = (USE_PROXY ? url : getPathFromUrl(url));

console.log('options.host = ' + host);
console.log('options.port = ' + port);
console.log('options.path = ' + path);
console.log('\n');

//Make the request
protocol.get({host: host, port: port, path: path}, function(res) {
    console.log('x-client-ip header: ' + res.headers['x-client-ip']);
    console.log('Status code: ' + res.statusCode);
    if ([301,302,303].indexOf(res.statusCode) > -1){
        console.log('location header : ' + res.headers["location"]);
        console.log('Redirect url: ' + combineUrls(res.headers["location"],url));
    } else {
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('Response body: ' + data.toString());
        });
    }
}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

In the above, the host/port/path specified in the request options are determined from the URL and the proxy configuration set (as is whether to use http or https library). To check that the correct proxy settings are used, I am checking the request IP read by the host server as follows:

1. http protocol: Response body from http://whatismyip.akamai.com/
2. https protocol: x-client-ip header from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

With no proxy set, these are the results:

1.

```
options.host = whatismyip.akamai.com
options.port = 80
options.path = /

x-client-ip header: undefined
Status code: 200
Response body: **.**.**.** (public IP)
```

2. 

```
options.host = en.wikipedia.org
options.port = 443
options.path = /wiki/Main_Page

x-client-ip header: **.**.**.** (public IP)
Status code: 200
Response body: <!DOCTYPE html> //etc...
```

However, if I try to use the proxy (which is routing the requests via a tethered mobile device and using its mobile network), I get the following results:

1.

```
options.host = 127.0.0.1
options.port = 6401
options.path = http://whatismyip.akamai.com

x-client-ip header: undefined
Status code: 400
Response body: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "http&#58;&#47;whatismyip&#46;akamai&#46;com", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;64fcff5a&#46;1605358006&#46;0
</BODY></HTML>
```

2. 

```
options.host = 127.0.0.1
options.port = 6401
options.path = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

x-client-ip header: **.**.**.** (Proxy IP)
Status code: 301
location header : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
Redirect url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

So there seem to be 2 issues when using the proxy settings - in the first request, the response code is http400 and the body suggests that the path provided is encrypted. What is strange is that sometimes I can get it to work if I rewrite the code and hardcode the settings in, e.g.:

```
http.get({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 6401,
    path: 'http://whatismyip.akamai.com/'
}, function (res) {
    console.log('Status code: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Response body: ' + data.toString());
    });
});
```

will return:

```
Status code: 200
Response body: **.**.**.** (Proxy IP)
```

So I am currently at a loss to explain why it fails in the earlier code.

In the second case with the https protocol, the response code of 301 is returned, but the redirect location matches the original URL, so there must be an issue with the way the path is presented when the request is forwarded to the host server.

*** Edit ***

As suggested, tried using the other request libraries. Example with axios below:

```
axios.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page',{
    proxy: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 6401
    }
}).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res.status);
    console.log(res.headers['x-client-ip']);
    //console.log(res.data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The Public IP was returned instead of the Proxy IP in this instance.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `axios` or `got` to make requests? They both support proxy

Comment: No reason I can't switch if I can get either of those to work. I've tried using axios, but it's still returning the public IP instead of the Proxy IP - see edit to original question for code.